# WordPress redirection is not working

Tags: php, redirect, wordpress

I need to redirect my page to my api service while `paypal-payment-redirect` page is called.The bellow code redirects as I expected.But it's not passing the Authorization token in header. Is there any way to resolve that?

```
<?php

function my_page_template_redirect()
{
    global $wppimsettings;
    if (isset($_COOKIE['login_token'])) {
        if (is_page('paypal-payment-redirect')) {
            $token = json_decode(str_replace('\\', '', $_COOKIE['login_token']));
            $data = array(
                'headers' => array(
                    'Authorization' => $token->token_type . ' ' . $token->access_token
                )
            );
            header("Authorization: {$token->token_type} {$token->access_token}");
            header("Location: {$wppimsettings['api_url']}purchaseHelper/paypalPayment");
            exit();
        }
    }

}

add_action('template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect');
```

Comment: try str_replace('\',''.................

Comment: There is no problem with the cookie .... only having problem with the `Authorization` header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP HEADER doc](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

The optional replace parameter indicates whether the header should replace a previous similar header, or add a second header of the same type. **By default it will replace, but if you pass in FALSE as the second argument you can force multiple headers of the same type.** For example:

```
<?php
header('WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate');
header('WWW-Authenticate: NTLM', false);
?>
```